# Remove extra white space at the left of ul element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to remove extra white space at the left of li elements but don't know how to do it.Although my margin and padding of ul is 0 but still there is some extra space at left.Please help! Here is the image:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="container">
            <!-- menu icon -->
            <div class="icon-close">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </div>

        <!-- menu -->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">HELP</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
  background: #202024 url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/uber/black-thread.png') repeat left top;
  left: -285px;  /* start off behind the scenes */
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 285px;
}

.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

.menu li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #636366;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    line-height: 45px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    width: 270px;
}
```

Comment: You have a `padding-left: 20px;` set on your `li`

Comment: I unchecked this property but still nothing changes! @Pierre

Comment: Did you also set the padding-left explicity to  0 ?

Comment: Are you sure this is your HTML and CSS? You don't currently have any element with the class name `.menu`.

Comment: Yes in body selector I set the padding and margin to 0px @RalfD'hooge

Comment: I edit my html code now you can check @TylerH

Comment: @AishaSalman Are you using Twitter Bootstrap or something? That code moves the list off the screen...

Comment: Yes I'm using bootstrap! @TylerH

Answer (score 2):

Consider setting padding-left:0 explicitly in your CSS as follows:

```
.menu li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #636366;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    line-height: 45px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    padding-left: 0; // <-- make sure to set this
    padding-top: 3px;
    width: 270px;     
}
```

Comment: setting ul element padding to 0 did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

add `margin: 0;` to `.menu li` - that should fix it (or at least `margin-left: 0`)

Comment: Nope! nothing change by doing this @Johannes

Comment: then there's got to be some other code which you didn't post that causes this

Comment: Did you clear the cache of your browser ?
Did you check your developer tool, to see where the padding or margin came from  ?

Comment: Yes I also did this @RalfD'hooge

Answer (score 1):

try to style your container with

```
.container{
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: I think everybody here misunderstood your question except @nonstop328.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

I think the only one to understand your question was [nonstop328](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37283917/811240). My answer is to make the text line up with the `border-bottom` on the list element, which is what I thought you wanted. I'll leave it here in case it helps you debug problems like this in the future, but consider marking the other answer as accepted.

---

Since the other answers and your comments suggest that removing `padding-left` and `margin-left` from `.menu li` (or explicitly setting it to `0`) does not work, we only have 2 other possibilities.

1. You have `padding-left` and/or `margin-left` set on `.menu li a`. In which case, either remove that or explicitly set it to `0`.
2. You have an `!important` flag set on the margin or padding somewhere else and commenting it out or even using your browser's developer console may make you *think* you have removed it, but in fact you have not.
   To find out if this is the case here is how you can do it in Chrome (FF is probably almost the same):

   - Right click on the element in the page and click on "Inspect element".
   - Click on the correct element in the DOM frame.
   - In the other frame make sure `styles` is selected. Click on the word `filter` and in there type in `margin` or `padding` and it will filter out all the CSS rules that add those attributes to the element.
   - Uncheck all rules with a non-zero margin-left, margin, padding-left or padding.
   - Wash, rinse and repeat for both of these CSS rules and both the `<li>` and `<a>` elements.

You can also get a visual representation of what is going on. In the DOM frame hover your mouse over both the `<a>` tag and the `<li>` tag. You will notice that the background for that element changes color. Blue is for the actual dimensions of the content of the element, green is for padding and orange is for margin. Like this:

[image: CSS hover]
In this example I have added a `margin-left` of 25 and `padding-left` of 20.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this so far :) @Mike